# Hardware question, off-topic, but no good close reason

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

This question is in the review queue for an edit, but it is off topic.  This has close votes as off-topic too broad, but that doesn't really fit because it is a question about putting hardware together.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228840/creating-simple-transmitter-receiver

I don't know if there's an SE site that fits, but none of the sites offered fit.  And it may still be too broad.

Wasn't there a close reason for 'not programming related'? I didn't see that as an option.

Comment: The "blatantly off-topic" close reason is only for close flags, not votes.  Just use the free-text option instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wasn't there a close reason for 'not programming related'?

There is:

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

In this case, I've picked Other and explained in the custom close reason why I think the question is off-topic. I agree that Too Broad does not apply here.

Comment: I guess the other topic was closed in favor of that one, or maybe I'm thinking of a flag.  I just tend to use that reason for people that might be able to update their question.